# Superconductivity at room temperature

Tags: superconductivity

Why superconductivity at room temperature is SO important that the physics world is running behind it like AI in computer science field?

Comment: Because cooling down an apparatus is expensive and may also be very impractical, or even impossible.

Comment: Because it will save a lot of energy losses in generation, transmission etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What applications would room temperature super conductors have?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88074/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of power is lost in electrical transmission lines,and though cooling to the temperature of liquid nitrogen is possible it is in most cases impractical. Room temperature superconductivity would save a huge amount of power being wasted and abolish the need for high tech hospital equipment such as NMRI scanners to have magnets cooled by liquid nitrogen. The same goes for the magnets of particle accelerators and tokomaks.